# Windows 10 BItLocked after dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 installation

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, ubuntu-18.04

Unfortunately I did not realize that Bitlocker has to be disabled when creating a dual boot of Windows 10 + Ubuntu 18.04.

Therefore I currently find my Windows partition locked with Bitlocker.

Unfortunately I cannot access the Bitlocker recovery keys through my Microsoft account because they have never been uploaded to the cloud; never knew there was such thing as bitlocker on my comoputer.

How can I recover my Windows OS partition? Would I have to uninstall Grub? If so, would my Windows OS boot without problems? And afterwards, would my Ubuntu also still boot?

Comment: Use your last disk image before the change.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I recover my Windows OS partition?

The only to recovery your data is with the recovery key.  You can download [it](https://onedrive.live.com/recoverykey).  You can visit that page on any OS.

Source: [BitLocker recovery keys](https://onedrive.live.com/recoverykey)

> Would I have to uninstall Grub?

You should be prepared to go back to the Windows Bootloader in the event it's required temporarily.

> would my Ubuntu also still boot?

Since your actions would only be temporary and reversible this shouldn't be a huge concern.  However, with any action like this, you should backup your valuable data.

Comment: @sir_olf - Your question doesn't ask how to do that.  You asked how to get your BitLocker recovery key.