# Can a computer reboot unexpectedly because of a BitLocked partition on dual boot with Windows and Linux?

Tags: reboot, bitlocker, dualboot

I just bought a new computer a few days ago with Windows 10 preinstalled. I did a dual boot with Xubuntu 18.04, and that causes to BitLock the Windows partition, as in this thread:

- [Windows 10 BItLocked after dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 installation](https://superuser.com/questions/1525879/windows-10-bitlocked-after-dual-boot-ubuntu-18-04-installation)

I didn't realize since I had not used the Windows partition after the dual boot.

Then, the computer started to reboot unexpectedly and very often. Since I never used it with Windows, I didn't suppose it was because of my Linux installation, I thought of a hardware problem, but when I got back to the store, the technician told me that I had a BitLocked the partition, and that was what caused the unexpected instant reboots

So is it possible that using Linux, on a computer with Windows BitLocker on a second partition, can cause the computer to reboot unexpectedly?

Answer (score 1):

Having a BitLocked Windows partition can't make the Linux system crash or hang. At most it can prevent Windows from booting. If your Linux system crashes it's not for that reason.

Comment: thanx for the answer. I have read on some places (ex https://qr.ae/pr18n1) that windows partition can hibernate instead of shutdown, if fast startup is enabled, then what happens if windows wake up from hibernation, could that explain the reboot ? and can that happens even if i'm on the linux partition ?